# Use multiple environments in .NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: asp.net, .net-framework-version, appsettings

I have .NET Framework 4.7.2 project that uses for a azure app service that uses for API calls.
I want to use a different appsettings.json for each environment, I have multiple environments (production, pre-production and more...)

I saw this docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1

But I didn't find something similar that works with .NET Framework.

How should I do it?

Comment: You can use `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` in .NET Old too. All Microsoft.Extensions.* packages are .NET Standard 2.0 packages

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but how will OP pass the desired environment from a .NET Framework Console App? Apart from environment variables

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not understanding the point you're trying to make. Sure environment variables could be used. Was there a deeper point you're trying to make and I'm just missing it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, do you have an example of how to do it in .Net framework 472? I don't know how to get the existing IConfiguration as a source and bind appsettings.json file to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a simple/supported way of getting the settings filename *override* functionality that NET core has for .Net Framework because it doesn't have or use environment variables and projects/executables in the same way.

But there is a library called [Slow Cheetah](https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah) that seems to do this, which allows you to automatically transform your app.config (or any file) when you press F5 in Visual Studio

I ended up using a single `App.config` file with different keys - see below.

From here, you'll just need to work out your own trigger for determining your Dev/Prod etc environment - probably a build step.

(In my case, I had a ClickOnce app that was either published/prod or not/dev - so this part was easy)

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Dev"
connectionString="..." />
  <add name="Prod"
connectionString="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```